# Automatically notify people when I leave/reach a location

Tags: gps, geolocation

Does anyone know of a way to automatically send a notification when I arrive or leave a location?

For example, I'd like to send a notification to my wife whenever I leave the office.

Does anyone know of a service that would do this? I'd prefer something stock/Google over some home-brew app, but I'm interested in hearing what's out there. I'm not really interested in a foursquare type of thing where I earn badges, it's more for communicating my location with one or two people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can have approaching/leaving a location as a trigger, and sending a text message as an action. I've read before of people setting it up to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I own Tasker but found it a bit daunting and never really set much up. I'll give it a shot and post results.

Comment: "Daunting", indeed. Handy, though.

Comment: Yeah, it does take a bit of getting used to. The internet is your friend.

Comment: "Tasker can do that" is like "Use jQuery" over on [so]. The go-to answer.

Comment: @AlEverett - Well, if it works, and is the best option, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @Saint: No, as long as "Use Tasker" isn't the entirety of the answer.

Comment: @AlEverett - Ah, well of course.

Answer (score 2):

Install IFTTT app into your phone. Create a IFTTT recipe (www.ifttt.com) that runs IF "Android Location" (you enter/leave an area on map) THEN "Android SMS" to a phone number. Theoretically it sounds easy. I am just about to test it how it works in practice :-)

Here is a ready IFTTT recipe as an example.
Message your partner when you leave work
https://ifttt.com/recipes/158448-message-your-partner-when-you-leave-work

Comment: IFTTT is probably not a good alternative. I tried it, creating recipes to do just ask you ask -- send an sms to spouse when leaving work. The recipe would trigger, but it would trigger anywhere from 1 to 4 hours after I left the geographic location. Apparently their polling is not spectacular (or they have too many users/recipes for their current servers to handle). I'll be deleting the app and giving tasker a try. It might be more difficult, but it doesn't rely on a web server polling your phone when it has a few free CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are several apps that purport to do this. Two that I found are:

- [AreYouThereYet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dunntech.areyouthereyet)
- [IHaveArrived](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.daddionts.I_Have_Arrived)

Answer (score 0):

[Life360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd) will notify you when anyone leaves or arrives from locations you set. You can create two locations for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [GPS share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kkinder.sharelocation&hl=en) app. It is simple to use and does exactly what its name says.

Answer (score 0):

You can try IFTTT ([IF This Then That](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt))

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) Answers here are supposed to be detailed and I don't see any detail here. Consider an [edit] and mention the usage of this app to achieve the goal in question.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but Google now let's you share your location directly from Google Maps.

In Google Maps go to Account -> Location Sharing. You can share the location for a set amount of time or until you revoke the permission.

For the notifications you can use [IFTTT recipes](https://ifttt.com/applets/158448p-send-a-message-from-your-android-phone-when-you-leave-work) (you don't need to have the app on the phone).